Cartesian tensor transformation and representations of $SO(3)$
I have hard times understanding the transformation of tensors, that probably stems from my shaky understanding of representation theory.
A cartesian tensor can be decomposed in three terms:
$$
T_{ij}=T + A_{ij} + S_{ij}
$$
where $T$ is the trace, $A$ is the antisymmetric part and $S$ is the symmetric part with trace 0. These three parts transform under rotations according to the $j=0,1,2$ representations of $SO(3)$.
How can I prove that e.g, the symmetric part indeed transforms as the $j=2$ representation of $SO(3)$? Sakurai says that it has 5 independent components, the same as the =2 representation of SO(3). But this is not a proof. I can find many objects with 5 components that do not transform as SO(3).
I tried to explicitly write down how the components transform in the case of an infinitesimal rotation around the $z$ axis.
For the antisymmetric part I find (the prime shows the rotated components):
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
A'_{yx} &=& A_{yx} \\
A'_{xz} &=& A_{xz}-\epsilon A_{yz} \\
A'_{yz} &=& A_{yz}+\epsilon A_{xz}\\
\end{eqnarray}
$$
which implies that the generator of the rotation is
$$
J_z=i\hbar\left(\begin{array}{c}
0&0&0\\
0&-1&0\\
1&0&0
\end{array}\right)
$$
This is indeed the generator of the $SO(3)$ representation with $j=1$ written in the basis $|x\rangle, |y\rangle, |z\rangle$.
For the symmetric traceless part I can do the same to find
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
S'_{xx} &=& S_{xx} \\
S'_{yy} &=& S_{yy} \\
S'_{xy} &=& S_{xy}\\
S'_{xz} &=& S_{xz} - \epsilon S_{yz} \\
S'_{yz} &=& S_{yz}+\epsilon S_{xz}
\end{eqnarray}
$$
And the generator of the rotation becomes
$$
J_z=i\hbar\left(\begin{array}{c}
0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&-1\\
0&0&0&1&0
\end{array}\right)
$$
This has the correct dimensionality to be a generator of $j=2$. But how do I see that this is indeed a generator? I mean, the generator with $j=2$ in the base of the eigenstates of the angular momentum is
$$
J_z=\hbar\left(\begin{array}{c}
-2&0&0&0&0\\
0&-1&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&0&2
\end{array}\right)
$$
And I assume that the $J_z$ I found is just this $J_z$ but in another coordinate basis. But what is this other basis? For the antisymmetric tensor it was the coordinate basis, but here I do not have a 5 dimensional coordinate basis.

It is quite unclear what you're asking.  Your claim on $T_{ij}$ holds only for $3\times 3$ matrices, and $T_{ij}$ will be a sum of $3\times 3$ matrices.  It's not clear what your prime means either.  At any rate, for $3\times 3$ matrices, the $L=1$ part are angular momenta, and the $L=2$ part (symmetric) are quadrupole moments (or alternatively the traceless moments of inertia).

The polynomials of degree $3$ in $(x,y,z)$ will contain an $L=3$ part, v.g. $(x+iy)^3\sim T_3^3$ in the spherical basis, and there are $10$ operators of degree constructed from $(x,y,z)$, and $r^2 (x+iy)\sim T^1_1$.  There is no antisymmetric part in this set of polynomial operators.

My question is this: the symmetric part of a cartesian tensor transforms according to the j=2 representation of SO(3). How can I see this? Sakurai says that it has 5 independent components, the same as the $j=2$ representation of SO(3). But this is not a proof. I can find many objects with 5 components that do not transform as SO(3).
I've modified my question, hope this makes it clear what I am asking.

The prime shows the new components after the infinitesimal rotation.

about which axis?

well... no.  The symmetric part of a Cartesian tensor does not transform by $j=2$.   Maybe what you call a "tensor" is actually an operator written as $3\times 3$ matrix?  It is true that any hermitian $3\times 3$ matrix can be decomposed as a sum of $L=0,1$ and $2$ tensors, but that's just an arbitrary $3\times 3$ matrix; that's not a Cartesian tensor.  A tensor operator can transform by any $j$, for instance $(x+iy)^3$ is the $m=3$ component of a tensor operator with $L=3$.  Again, the decomposition of a $3\times 3$ matrix is a sum of $3\times 3$ matrices...

The question is very unclear so maybe what the OP means is that any matrix
$$
M=\pmatrix{M_{xx}&M_{xy}&M_{xz}\\ M_{yx}&M_{yy}&M_{yz}\\ M_{zx}&M_{zy}&M_zz}
$$ can be written in the form
$$
M= \frac12 \left(M+M^\top\right) + \frac12 \left(M-M^\top\right). 
$$
Clearly the matrices
$$
S=\left(M+M^\top\right)\, ,\qquad A=\left(M-M^\top\right)
$$
are symmetric and antisymmetric, respectively.  $A$ for instance would be of the form
$$
A=\pmatrix{0&M_{xy}-M_{yx}& M_{xz}-M_{zx}\\ -M_{xy}+M_{yx}&0 &M_{yz}-M_{zy}\\
M_{zx}-M_{xz}&M_{zy}-M_{yz}&0}
$$
and $L_z$ is Cartesian is
$$
L_z=\pmatrix{0 & 1 &0\\ -1 &0&0 \\ 0 &0 &0}
$$
so obviously $A$ is proportional to a multiple of $L_z$ and indeed to a sum of angular momenta, or which there are $3$, and which transform as the components of an $L=1$ tensor.
The symmetric part (there are 6 independent entries) can be written in terms of the trace and $5$ other matrices.  For instance, the entry $(1,3)$ is
$M_{xz}+M_{zx}$.  One can then verify that, under commutation with the (antisymmetric) $L_k$'s, the $5$ remaining entries transform into linear combinations of each others and nothing else, so they are proportional to entries in $T^m_2$, a tensor with $L=2$.
It’s easy enough to very that $[L_k,S_{ij}]$ is a linear combo of other $S_{ij}$.  You can “see” this because the commutator is antisymmetric, and $L_k$ is antisymmetric, while $S_{ij}$ is symmetric, so $[L_k,S_{ij}]$ will be symmetric.

"so they are proportional to entries in $_^2$, a tensor with =2."
This is actually my question. Why are they proportional to entries in a $T_2^m$ tensor?

You need to try it.  There are 5 so as soon as you find the combination  so that $[L_z,T^2_2]=2T^2_2$ and $[L_+,T^2_2]=0$ you are done as you can lower to the other $m$ from $T^2_2$.  Try $M_{xx}-M_{yy}-2i M_{xy}$ or something like this.  You can verify that the 5 traceless entries of $S$ satisfy $[L_k,S_{ij}]$ is a combo of all the $S_{k\ell}$, and that’s also enough (this doesn’t give the basis).
